# Checking Gmail account in order to keep track of space been used in percentage with Python

Tags: python, windows, gmail, storage

Using Python, I need to read the total amount of storage of Gmail account in order to keep track of space been used in percentage as seen from the Gmail page.

Example: if it says 10GB of 15GB (66%) than a file should record the number – 66.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the requests lib and make a basic request to Google Drive's api as mail and drive share the same storage space. You can check the details of the API 
[here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/drive/v3/drive.about.get?fields=storageQuota&_h=4&)

```
import requests
import json

def main():
    req = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=storageQuota&key={YOUR_API_KEY}')
    json_response = json.loads(req.content)
    //Process the json response to your free will

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The result of the request is something like this

```
200 OK

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
content-encoding:  gzip
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Mon, 03 Sep 2018 08:42:33 GMT
expires:  Mon, 03 Sep 2018 08:42:33 GMT
server:  GSE
transfer-encoding:  chunked
vary:  Origin, X-Origin

{
 "storageQuota": {
  "limit": "16106127360",
  "usage": "15054153867",
  "usageInDrive": "15022609247",
  "usageInDriveTrash": "0"
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm behind a proxy. I've tried many solutions like this:
proxies = {"http":"http://rpy3bpb:password@10.204.68.5:8080"}
 r = requests.get("http://www.example.com/", proxies=proxies)
The error is:
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /drive/v3/about?fields=storageQuota&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel

Comment: The proxy you are using is probably _banned_ by Google as there is a limit for API requests. You can check with a different proxy but it won't be reliable if there are other users for that proxy as well. Another reminder don't forget to change your API key in the URL as it will return status 401 Unauthorized otherwise.